# Using unittest to test command line arguments

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am writing unittest to see if the input taken from command line is being properly stored. Right not how things are set is that when I run the the unittest it opens up the terminal and I have to write something in it which it then takes to in and tests. What I want is to write the test case in way that I can pass arguments to the unittest which get substituted for the terminal output automatically and I get the result. Here is my sample code:

```
class terminal_input(cmd.Cmd):
    user_database = {}
    def do_add_customer(self):
    """ Add a new customer to the database"""
        name = input("Enter your name: ") 
        id = 123
        user_database[id] = name

class terminal_input_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add_new_customer (self, name, id):
        ticketing_system = terminal_input()
        ticketing_system.do_add_customer()
        #Do something here that name argument goes into input rather than typing it out
        self.assertEqual(name,ticketing_system.user_database[id])

if __name__ == '__main__':
test_case_1 = terminal_input_test()
test_case_1.test_add_new_customer(foo, 123)
```

Comment: Just `unittest.mock` out the function and provide whatever user input you want

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I will go about it in this particular case?

Comment: Have a look through [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and make an *attempt*, at least.